# How to detect Shake Gesture while application in Background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gesture-recognition, motion-detection, handshake

I'm currently working on a music player app, and like the iPod application, I would like to shuffle songs with shake gesture.

I'm implementing motion methods like Apple recommends to, and in foreground everything works fine.

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

But I just can't figure out how to call those methods from background. I've looked all over the internet, and there's not threads about this.

**first things first: is it possible?**

Thanx!

Comment: I don't think you app will recieve these call when running in the background.

Comment: Another kind of methods then? Is there a way to detect motion gesture from background? If Apple does it, there might be a way! :P

Comment: If Apple does it, does not mean you are allowed to do it. The Shake for next song only work when I have to iPod app open.

Comment: You are so dem right! Shake only works while app is open...
I always thought that worked both ways. Thank you! I have now have the task to explain it with dumb words to my client :P

Comment: That's a common pain for all iphone developers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible now, whether you use iOS 4 or any lower SDK version.