# can a iOS application receive shake gesture while it is in background in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I got to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858792/how-to-detect-shake-gesture-while-application-in-background) which says that it cant be done in iOS 4. Now it has been a year ,so these restrictions still apply to iOS 5? can it be done in iOS 5 ?
any alternative method to do that ?

Comment: I don't think this is an "restriction".  Assuming that background apps can receive the user interactions, then how does one distinguish which background app(s) were those interaction events supposed for?

Comment: simple. the apps which have registered them as the receiver of events , all of them would get the events

Comment: The issue at hand as stated in my comment was not a technical issue.  Rather it was a logistic one.  Let's say, you have a background app that you will change to next song when you received shake gesture, ...and the user is using another app in forgroud  that also is using shake gesture...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it still can't be done. Applications in the background do not receive any events from the user. The only exception would be applications that play music, and can get the events from the Play/Pause, Next, Prev buttons.

Comment: Don't mind but just to add in this, app will also get notified from background if location tracking is enabled in UIBackgroundModes Apart from music notifications